# Can't assign values to new column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, set

I loaded the built-in dataset "Iris" into my environment.
I want to make a new column called "Petal.Area" where I multiply petal.length and petal.width for each row. I created the new column and filled it with blank data. When I try to use a "for" loop to assign values for each value in the column "Petal.Area", I get an error message (The multiplication symbol that I used isn't signficiant for factors. But when I did typeof() on the elements in the dataframe, R said that they were doubles. I tried to cast the factors into doubles, but I got another error message (NAs introduced by coercion)

```
Petal_Data <- iris
Petal_Data$Petal.Area <- NA

for (i in 1: (ncol(Petal_Data)-1) ) {
 
 Petal_Data[6,i] = Petal_Data[3,i] * Petal_Data[4,i]
 # this didnt work: Petal_Data$Petal.Area[i] = Petal_Data$Petal.Length[i] * Petal_Data$Petal.Width[i]  
 # this didnt work Petal_Data[6, i] = as.numeric(as.character(Petal_Data[3, i])) * as.numeric(as.character(Petal_Data[4, i]))
 }

print(Petal_Data)
```

Comment: R is vectorized. You don't need a loop here at all. `Petal_Data$Petal.Area <- Petal_Data$Petal.Length * Petal_Data$Petal.Width` will give you your new column. You seem to be getting rows and columns mixed up in your loop anyway.

Comment: `within(Petal_Data, Petal.Area <- Petal.Length * Petal.Width)`

Comment: You're accessing the data incorrectly. It is `Petal_Data[row, column]` and not the other way around. You should use `Petal_Data[i,6]` for example.

Comment: You could also load dplyr and use ```Petal_Data <- iris %>% mutate(Petal.Area = Petal.Length * Petal.Width)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is not necessary;
`Petal_Data$Petal.Area <- Petal_Data$Petal.Length * Petal_Data$Petal.Width`
(thanks to Allan Cameron)